# Webpage footer remains on bottom of browser window

Tags: html, toolbar, css-float, css

I want my footer (on some pages) to remain fixed to the bottom of the browser window regardless of the height of the content.  Similar to some of the toolbars you see fixed on the bottom of the browser window on sites like [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) and the meebo toolbar (e.g. [abduzeedo.com](http://abduzeedo.com/)).

I did some quick searching and I see some jQuery scripts and CSS hacks with users complaining about IE incompatibility, etc... is there a good standard way of doing this?  Even with meebo and facebook, it seems like the toolbar can kind of jump a little as you scroll whereas the CSS solutions look very solid.  Is there a simple CSS solution?  I assume it's something along the lines of making the footer have absolute positioning with bottom: 0...

Comment: Hey @at... did it work? I've noticed you haven't selected an answer yet.

Comment: I just hadn't had a chance to test with IE, but credited you with the answer anyway.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something to "stick" to the bottom, [you should use the css **fixed** position](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp). This will locate it to the bottom of the window.

Using "absolute" will not be correct, because it will located the div relative to the first non-static element. Most of the time this is the window, but that doesn't have to be the case.

Html code:

```
<div class="bottom"><h1>Add to bottom</h1></div>
```

Css code:

```
div.bottom {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:200px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    border:solid 4px red;
}
```

Comment: position:fixed is exactly what I was looking for.  Why does a search for this yield so many JavaScript scripts and CSS hacks to make it work?  Is there any issue, compatibility or otherwise, with using position:fixed?

Comment: @at well... A lot of times people think they know css... But they don't. It is true what Julian says... The implementation of position in IE6 can be quite nasty. That's why many people use hacks for it. I'd recommend a conditional script for IE6 and lower if you have problems. But... It should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good tutorial from a guy called Soh Tanaka - http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/facebook-style-footer-admin-panel-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning in CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/TMD9X/

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please setup a fiddle for me to illustrate? Thanks.